# .NET 6 Object Not Allowing Null when <Nullable> is Disabled

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0

We recently upgraded our solution to .NET 6 and we are having issues with an object not being null as we would expect.

I have read the documentation for nullable types on .NET 6 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies). We elected to **disable** the *Nullable* setting in our projects for the time-being, while we get the code working. Because we have disabled the nullable setting, I would expect that the object behaves as it previously did, being a nullable type.

Please see code below.

## Project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

## Object

```
public class Lockbox : IEntity
    {
       public SegregationGroup SegregationGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

## Service

```
var lockbox = remittanceList.FirstOrDefault()?.RemittanceFile.Lockbox;

var isPlbOnly = remittanceList.Any(r => r.RemittancePLBs.Any()) && allThe2100s.All(r2100 => r2100?.RemittanceCLP?.SegregationGroupId != lockbox.DefaultPlbSegregationGroupId);
            if (isPlbOnly)
            {
                var segGroup = lockbox?.SegregationGroup != null ? lockbox.SegregationGroup : segDefault;
                segGroups.Add(segGroup);
            }
            return segGroups;
```

As you can see, we depend on checking whether or not that SegregationGroup object is null. On our previous framework, the object would be null and we would set the property accordingly. With .NET 6, the object always returns with the following:

[image: Image of code debugging]

I've also tried turning Nullable back ON, and using ? annotations to signal a nullable type, and also setting the object = null in the constructor, but none of this worked. We'd prefer to have Nullable disabled for now.

I have also made sure to set the Nullable setting to Disabled for all projects involved.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Something in your code is setting `lockbox?.SegregationGroup` to `default<SegregationGroup>`. Things don't magically become un-null - unless you code them that way

Comment: Looks like it's set to a new instance somewhere else in your code. You probably want to check the usage of its setter. If no use can be found, as I saw it has an `IEntity` so I guess it's a DB model, maybe ORM is doing it. You can use debugger to watch that lockbox to narrow down when did `Lockbox` got populated.

Comment: @Flydog57 I will double check our code, but that wouldn't line up with why the object was null as expected before we upgraded the framework.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang Good thoughts, I will try down this path. Appreciate the ideas!

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang It seems you were correct, it looks like our ORM is doing it. Now, I'm seeing issues with FirstOrDefault() returning a default object that is non-null, where the constructor clearly sets it as null.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem. Taking a shot based on screenshots and are you by chance using InsightDb and upgrade it as well as part of this? If so, I think that is a recent problem with newer versions of the library where this is now the intended functionality.